# Alt+Tab opens Nautilus instead of Application Switcher

Tags: unity, nautilus, shortcut-keys, compiz

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> used to open the Compiz *Application Switcher* (desired behaviour). Now, when I use this key combination, a *Nautilus* window is opened at `~/` (unexpected behaviour) and the *Application Switcher* does not start.

While *Nautilus* is the first icon in my Unity *Launcher* Menu, rearranging the order does not affect the behaviour (always a *Nautilus* window is invoked by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>).

I've double checked that Compiz has <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> bound to *Application Switcher* > *Next Window (All windows)*.

The adherent hotkey does not appear to be a Compiz setting, since an "advanced search" for `<alt>Tab` under Compiz ("Settings value" only) returns only the *Application Switcher* binding.

How can I find out why Nautilus is starting by this key combo, and why this overrides the Compiz binding?

Ubuntu 16.04; Compiz 0.9.12.3;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Ubuntu *Keyboard > Shortcuts > Home Folder* was set to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for some reason.